# Problemas em configurar Gradiente no CSS

Tags: css, css3

Quero colocar um plano de fundo na pagina Web com efeito de gradiente, mas é esse resultado que estou tendo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta muito feio.

Eu utilizei essa configuração no CSS;

```
body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color:#205E99;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(255,255,255,.4), rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,.4)); 
}
```

Sendo que o efeito que quero que tenha é semelhante á esse;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é que eu faço?

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim ficará um gradiente semelhante ao que deseja:

```
<div class="gra"></div>

.gra{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff, #0000FF);
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Só uma dica para encorpar a resposta, é que o tamanho do "container" vai influênciar também no resultado que ele deseja. No caso atual dele o Body não está pegando nem 100% do Height da Tela. E isso irá influênciar, mas quando ele for adicionar o restando do conteúdo isso era se resolver.

Comment: @MichaelAlves se o height ou width for muito pequeno ficará feio o resultado mas quando almentado para 1000px ambos ainda fica bonito. https://jsfiddle.net/9m9PV/65/

Answer (score -1):

Com a referência que você postou, acredito que tem melhorar o código do gradiente, recomendo usar o padrão seguinte:

```
body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 10%, #205E99 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 10%, #205E99 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background:     -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 10%, #205E99 90%); /* IE10 */
    background:      -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 10%, #205E99 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background:         linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 10%, #205E99 90%); /* W3C */
}
```

OBS: Geralmente eu pego no site http://uigradients.com/ e modifico as cores.

Comment: Se quiser mexer o angulo, basta mexer o `deg`

Answer (score -2):

Usando o poderoso [Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

```css
.gradient{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;

  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#a0a5ff+0,2737fe+100 */
  background: rgb(160,165,255); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(160,165,255,1) 0%, rgba(39,55,254,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(160,165,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(39,55,254,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(160,165,255,1) 0%,rgba(39,55,254,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(160,165,255,1) 0%,rgba(39,55,254,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(160,165,255,1) 0%,rgba(39,55,254,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(160,165,255,1) 0%,rgba(39,55,254,1) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a0a5ff', endColorstr='#2737fe',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Comment: pq o downvote? isso não responde a pergunta?